# Getting error in VS code when trying to create virtual environment on windows

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I am trying to create a virtual environment in VS code to make a flask app. After I run the command in the VS code terminal `pip install virtualenv` everything downloads find but I get the error  WARNING: The script virtualenv.exe is installed in

```
C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

Then when I try to create my virtual environment by using this command `virtualenv env` I get the error

```
virtualenv : The term 'virtualenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Comment: Have you tried to do what it suggests, i.e. add the directory `C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Script` to the PATH environment variable?

Answer (score 2):

From [Installing packages using pip and virtual environments](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/)

> If you are using Python 3.3 or newer, the venv module is the
> preferred way to create and manage virtual environments. venv is
> included in the Python standard library and requires no additional
> installation.

```
python -m venv venv
```

To run the scripts just type. No need to put in the complete location:

```
./venv/Scripts/activate
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Python from the Windows Store? You'd better avoid it.

You can download the python from the [official site](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

And then create the virtual environment through `venv`.

You can refer to [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_create-a-virtual-environment) for more details of the virtual environment created.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the directory *(as mentioned by you)*

```
C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
```

is not added to your PATH

Consider this link [Add to the PATH on Windows 10](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/) and add the directory to the PATH.
It's gonna solve your problem.
The same issue happened to me it solve it as said above.

Comment: The same suggestion is mentioned by 
@md2perpe  in the comment under. I just try to simply it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `cmd` and then type:

```
PATH=C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts
```

in this case this is the path but it might be different in yours
so just type the path that is specified in the warning.

I also had this issue and spend more than three hours fixing this.